# Quick Tips/Tooltips

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm looking to implement some tooltips that will show quick tips to users on a web app. They will need to shown only once and can be turned off from a users preferences.

Anyone developed anything like this before? Looking for some ideas/suggestions for how to implement such functionality...

Flow has a good implementation of them as does Facebook:

[image]

[image]

**Just to clarify I'm not asking how to create ToolTips using jQuery or other frameworks rather I am asking how to show tooltips based on user interaction when they first view an app and then no longer see them and can also disable them from a user preference in personal settings**

Comment: [google: jquery tooltips](http://www.google.co.za/search?q=jquery+tooltips&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Not looking for jQuery Tooltips. I'm looking for ways to implement them in a tour guide manner

Answer (score 2):

jQuery tools has a good implementation. It's light too.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: Not looking for jQuery Tooltips. I'm looking for ways to implement them in a tour guide manner